# Honey Extension modification

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am a developer , I am using honey extension for my online shopping , mostly their coupons are
expired and they are saying that it has been used before 3 hours by abc user.

(1) i want suggestion that what modifications or new features requires for such extension to create
user trust ( i am tired from honey), so i can create prototype of it for my own use to test it.

(2) And how they getting the fact/data that user has used that coupon or its fake?

Comment: hey can anyone please answer my question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63923882/honey-extension-amount-detection-algorithm

Answer (score 0):

From a development point of view you can always download the honey crx using a tool like this.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin?hl=en

A lot of the code will probably be minified, but you can get an idea of how the extension is working.
You'll also quickly see that a lot of the logic is actually done server-side which the extension communicates with to validate data like the coupons expiration.